# get jQuery mobile datebox running (TypeError: a.mobile.datebox is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I cannot get the jQueryMobile - DateBox running. It is not shown at all and I get some JS errors. Here is my code:

Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<form id="formular" name="formular" method="post" action="enquiry.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Arrival</td>
      <td><input name="arrival" id="frm_arrival" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' value="<?php echo $arrival; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- .... -->
  </table>
</form>
```

The datepicker is not shown and Firebug gives me the following errors:

```
TypeError: a.mobile.datebox is undefined
TypeError: jQuery.mobile.datebox is undefined
```

The error should be on line 11 of `jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js`. This is the line:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options.lang, {
```

I cannot find the error. Is it a jQuery conflict? Am I using `jQueryMobile - DateBox` the wrong way? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are all of your files loaded.. i.e No 404 errors?

Comment: @socialrel8: There are no 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Switch these two lines, I'm guessing the first one depends on the second one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

You need to include the actual datebox file in your header. The German version is only a translation. It doesn't contain the datebox plugin itself.

Arrange your script tags like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.datebox-something-something.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, its a good practice to call all external style sheets before any linked JS files.

Comment: I tried this but that didn't changed anything. More solutions?

Comment: @testing - I'll need to see the site better, can you try to put it up to the web so I can mess with it?

Comment: @PitaJ: I added the core plugin `jqm-datebox-1.1.0.core.min.js` but now nothing happens. I will go for another datepicker ...

Comment: fwiw, "nothing" happened because DateBox was horribly broken for a while there - all is well again (I think).

Comment: Additionally, yes, you need to include .core - the translations only take care of the strings, .core does all (most) of the work

Comment: @PitaJ : I sorted by script but I received this message "TypeError: d is undefined" any idea ?

Comment: @googleuser - I would have to see your code before I could help you.